# Cardinality of the ranks of the constructible universe

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, model-theory

First time I encounter the Constructible universe $L$ and the definition given in Jech is the following:

- $L_0=\emptyset$,
- $L_{\alpha+1}=\operatorname{def}(L_\alpha)$,
- $L_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}L_\alpha$.

Where we have $\operatorname{def}(M)=\{X\subseteq M:\text{ X is definable in }(M,\in)\}$

My doubt is what's the cardinality of $L_{\omega+1}$. From the definitions it would seem it's countable since $L_{\omega}$ is countable, so is the number of $n$-*tuples* and so will all the finite sequences of elements of $L_{\omega}$. We also have the number of $\{\in\}$-*formulas* is countable so it would seem that $L_{\omega+1}$ must also be countable. Is this correct? If so since $L$ is a model of $ZFC$ which can prove $\mathcal{P}(\omega)\subseteq V_{\omega+1}$ it would seem the constructible universe thinks $L_{\omega+1}$ is uncountable. Is this also correct?

Comment: Please don't use images. They are not searchable, and they are not accessible (screen readers have a hard time parsing them, making the post unavailable to people who use screen readers). They also cannot be rendered in a manner that accounts for the display being used by the viewer. I realize this is a fair chunk of text, but you should take the time to type it out using MathJax.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok it will take me a while

Comment: Yes, it is countable and $L$ also knows that it is countable. But the $V$ hierarchy of $L$ is not the same as the $L$ hierarchy.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the reply. The question seems very silly now. Should I delete it?

Comment: Don't delete. Someone else may find it useful. It's not a silly Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that $L_{\omega+1}$ is countable, but it's not correct that $L$ thinks it is uncountable.  Although $L$ satisfies $V=L$, it does not satisfy $V_\alpha=L_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.  Every set in the $V$ hierarchy eventually shows up in the $L$ hierarchy, but typically at a later stage.  So $L_{\omega+1}$ does not contain all of the subsets of $\omega$ that are in $L$; in fact, you have to go all the way up to $L_{\omega_1^L}$ to capture all of the subsets of $\omega$ in $L$.

Comment: For the OP, a concrete example of a set in $V_{\omega+1}$ but not in $L_{\omega+1}$ is the set of the natural numbers that are Gödel numbers of the true sentences in arithmetic. It's a subset of $\omega$, so it's in $V_{\omega+1}$, but its not being in $L_{\omega+1}$ is a consequence of Tarski's undefinability theorem.